# Program for extracting subtitle text from MKV files

Tags: subtitles, matroska

Is there a free program that can extract the text from embedded subtitles in MKV files? **I don't want to remove the subtitles.** I just want to get the plain-text from them. I want to save my favorite quotes from various shows and movies without having to manually open up a text editor and type it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mkvextract from [MKVToolnix](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/) can extract tracks and attachments from a Matroska container.

Comment: great tool. I used it some time ago to extract the english subtitles from movie and later to add translated subtitles to the movie again. :-)

Comment: Well, that lets me extract the subtitle tracks but I can't open the subtitles in a text editor without a bunch of nonsense characters coming up. Is there a way to get just the plain-text? Not the entire track itself as raw data. Is there any good subtitle editing programs out there?

Comment: You'll need to postprocess using something like awk or a subtitle editor if just want raw text. And if you're getting a bunch of nonsense characters then either you're extracting the wrong track or you need a better text editor.

Comment: I've got the right track. It's a VOB subtitle. But Notepad++ doesn't handle subtitles apparently.

Comment: Oh, *VOB* subtitles. Try Tesseract then or something.

Comment: How do I use this to extract the subtitles?

Answer (score 4):

I use the program [Subtitle Edit](http://www.nikse.dk/subtitleedit/) to extract subtitles from MKV files:

1. Open the program
2. Click on menu "File"
3. Select "Import subtitle from Matroska..."
4. A file window opens. Navigate to and select the .mkv file of interest
5. Wait a minute or so (depending on your CPU's power).
6. The subtitle is presented to you in SE's subtitle window.
7. Do whatever you want to the text and save it.

Answer (score 0):

I use the program Subtitle Edit to extract subtitles from MKV files:
Drag and drop the mkv-file on Subtitle Edit. If Subtitle Edit finds any sub, select File and Save as... Done!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), particularly the bits in **bold**; then edit your answer to follow the guidelines there. Thanks!